# Count without duplicates

Tags: sql, postgresql, count

I'd like to count column values without any duplicates.

In the given example, I'd expect the SQL query to sum up column a to 6 (every value counted once)

[image: datatable]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
select count(distinct a)
from table
```

Comment: Ok, this works perfect. Thank you... My mistake was, that I always had some attributes in my select and got everything grouped up...

Comment: Sorry Stu, I was wrong about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70725548/61305).