# How to order by multiple columns with same datatype

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-order-by

I want to sort multiple columns at the same time meaning I do not want to sort first column then second column which sql server order by generally does. Below is the example of how I want the result should be. Note that all column have same datatype.Also, Note that one of the columns in a row only have data.

I have a table that have values

| FirstName | LastName | MiddleName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| matt |  |  |
|  | jeff |  |
| dave |  |  |
|  | TomBrady |  |
|  |  | zedaya |
|  | Mccafrey |  |
|  |  | tom |

I want to sort this table by all the values in the three columns such that rows should populate as per the ascending or descending order of each value in the row.

Output should be:

| FirstName | LastName | MiddleName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| dave |  |  |
|  | jeff |  |
| matt |  |  |
|  | Mccafrey |  |
|  |  | tom |
|  | TomBrady |  |
|  |  | zeday |

I have 3 columns in which each row will have only of value of the three columns. I need to sort all the rows irrespective of the column (basically consider all the values appear in a single column, and sort). In the example above, dave is lowest according to sort order, so that row should come first. following by jeff row, followed by Maccafrey, Matt, Tom, TomBrady, Zedaya.

The right solution has been ticked as correct. Used Contact to order by all the fields at the same time.

Comment: Have you tried appending `ORDER BY FirstName asc, LastName asc, MiddeName asc` to your query? (iirc there might be a "NULLS FIRST" or "NULLS LAST" as well in TSql)

Comment: Tried. It didn't work out.

Comment: Are your blanks blank strings or null?

Comment: Columns are not nulls, so empty strings.

Comment: Please update your question to show what output you get from your actual query, including when you use `ORDER BY`

Comment: I do not have it now. But it order by values by each columns when I use order by column1 asc, column2 asc, column3 asc but doen't order by all columns at the same time. In the above example, Jeff and Matt is ordered in that column but Dave is coming last row and Tom is coming as first row.

Comment: yup, One of the columns will only have data.

Comment: I really don't understand the logic behind the expected results, can you explain?

Comment: `order by coalesce(nullif(firstname, ''), nullif(lastname, ''), middlename)`

Comment: @AaronBertrand thank you for taking the time to let me know 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sample data was ambiguous and misleading. If you really just want to order by whatever column isn't `''`, and given your assurance that no columns are `NULL` and there are no `' '` etc., you can use `CONCAT`, which will simply munge whatever value is not empty with two empty strings:

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName, MiddleName
  FROM dbo.t
  ORDER BY CONCAT(firstname, lastname, middlename);
```

Output:

| FirstName | LastName | MiddleName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| dave |  |  |
|  | jeff |  |
| matt |  |  |
|  | Mccafrey |  |
|  |  | tom |
|  | TomBrady |  |
|  |  | zedaya |

- example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=da9b23247c732a645ccfd6faddbcf9e4)

Answer (score 1):

Try converting the blanks to ascii values that are last in the table and sorting, does this work for you?

```
select *
from t
order by 
  IsNull(NullIf(firstname,''),Char(255)),
  IsNull(NullIf(lastname,''),Char(255)),
  IsNull(NullIf(middlename,''),Char(255))
```

[Example Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=75a05a7851914277c289f48c3885bc00)

Comment: The example you provided seems working. but when I'm trying the same in sql server, it is not.

Comment: tried this. insert into t select '','jeff',''
insert into t select 'dave','',''
insert into t select '','','zedaya'
insert into t select '','Mccafrey',''
insert into t select '','','tom'
insert into t select '','TomBrady',''
insert into t select 'matt','',''
Didn't workout.

Comment: When I try your data in the [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=70e4400c8c0bb16519a5fa2a28cd9752) it *seems* to look correct, can you elaborate on what didn't workout?

Comment: Ok perhaps I haven't fully clocked the desired results.

Comment: Thanks @AaronBertrand for the clarification, i'll remove this the case expression is clearly the better method.